# Is it possible to replace a class via css files without touchig the html file

Tags: css, font-awesome

Is there any way to change a class used in html file without editing the file?!

My case: I can't edit the template files (I don't have access), but I can define a css file to be loaded as the last one. I need to replace some classes name with something else somehow. Is there any tricky way?

Comment: You can create CSS rules that are more specific than the rules defined prior to yours, so that yours will take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Well... that depends on what you mean by "without touching the file".

You have to find some way to change the class to the one you want. You can do this by putting a more specific CSS rule as j08691 point out in the comment or you can change it using javascript.

Either way you'll have to put that css or js in the html. You can put them directly on page using style or script tags respectively or you can use a .css or .js external file. Either way you will have to change the original HTML file.

Other thing you can do is to put this html in a frame or iframe element and include the css or js you need.